# How can I configure Universal Image Loader to display images from https?

Tags: android, https, universal-image-loader

I have problem with Universal Image Loader when my connection to server is https. I can display images with http but not with https connection. How can I set sslSocketFactory in UIL ? My UIL code is like below;

```
Map<String,String> authHeaders = new HashMap<>();
authHeaders.put("token", LocalStorage.getUserToken(ctx));

DisplayImageOptions defaults = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300, true, true, false))
    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_image_fail)
    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_image_fail)
    .cacheOnDisk(true)
    .cacheInMemory(true)
    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    .extraForDownloader(authHeaders)
    .build();

ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder configsBuilder = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(ctx)
    .imageDownloader(new AuthImageDownloader(ctx))
    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaults);
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(configsBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Can you find out if your ssl certificate is invalid?

Comment: @petey It is a valid self signed certificate. I have no problems with other service calls. I also use Picasso and send https request and can take image. How can I configure ssl in UIL ?

Comment: You should add in your question that you use self signed certificate, because it is the reason of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kickoff sample:

```
public class SslRuinedDownloader extends BaseImageDownloader {

    public SslRuinedDownloader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(String url, Object extra) throws IOException {
        HttpsURLConnection conn = super.createConnection(url, extra);

        //here you go
        conn.setSSLSocketFactory(...);
        return conn;
    }
}

ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .imageDownloader(new SslRuinedDownloader(getApplicationContext()))
        .build();
```

Comment: now Iedited my  AuthImageDownloader and worked. Thanks